# After crop video output file not generated using ffmpeg android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

**I have cropped video using ffmpeg command after convert output media file not generating. I have used below command for crop video.**

```
final String[] cmd={-version, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170915_033023.mp4, -s, 720x1184, -vf, crop=480:480, setdar=1:1, setsar=1:1, -c:a, copy, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170915_033038.mp4};
```

Comment: any error you get?

Comment: remove -version and add -y like this { -y, -i ..... so on }.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper https://pastebin.com/ZvJWHqre  i got this error after add -y and remove -version

Comment: On which os you are trying to do this? 6.0 or below. If you are using 6.0 or above then you need to use another ffmpeg library.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I have used  compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2' library and i need support in 4.4.2 above all version

Comment: I used this way and it works for me. 
String cmd = "-y -i myfilepath.mp4 -s 480x480 -vf crop=480:480,setdar=1:1,setsar=1:1 -c:a copy myNewfile.mp4"
                 String[] command = cmd.split(" ");
                 execFFmpegBinary(command);